# Multiline HTML label has too many lines

Tags: html, axis-labels

I have a problem with a label which is the title of y axis on a chart. My problem is that when the title is too long, the label has 3 lines, which makes my axis title overlapping with the numbers on the axis. I would like to shorten the label to 2 lines even when there are many characters in the label.
For example I have:

```
some text
-
some text
```

and I need

```
some text
- some text
```

`-` cannot be removed. For the label I need code something like that:

```
<label style="" title="long title">I already shorten title</label>
```

Comment: Where is the code for your chart?

Comment: I'm using highcharts library and I need only to shorten this label. I set my title as html because I need tooltip.